# tinyscrollbar within a (bootstrap ) Modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, tinyscrollbar

I'm going crazy because I don't get the tinyscrollbar script working since 3 hours! I try to load it in a modal box but I can't figure out the  of tinyscrollbar to update as soon as I open the modal box. I already tried many - not for me working - solution from around the web.

So the code inside the modal box looks like this:

```
<div class="et-place-main-text">
                        <div class="scrollbar"><div class="track"><div class="thumb"><div class="end"></div></div></div></div>
                        <div class="viewport">
                            <div class="overview">
                            <?php the_field('content_modal_box');?>                 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div> <!-- .et-place-main-text -->
```

Now I need the correct code to kick `tinyscrollbar_update();` as soon as someone opens the modal with this link `#myModal-<? the_ID(); ?>`...

It would be great if someone has an idea.

Comment: I'm going crazy with that. So maybe anyone who has an idea?!

Comment: I'm implementing this scrollbar too, and it doesn't work within MODAL :(

Answer (score 0):

Trigger Your scrollbar on **'shown.bs.modal'**:

```
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {               
    scrollbar_init(); // trigger scrollbar after modal shown
});
```